# UITextField to change size to fix text content

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, viewcontroller

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a UITextField. I have the cell in a tableview inside my view controller.

```
let cellText : UITextField = {
    let secureText = UITextField()
    secureText.isSecureTextEntry = true
    secureText.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return secureText
}()
```

I want to change the size of the textField based on the amount of text that is inside the text field.

note* I do need the this to be a UITextField field because I want the text to go through as a isSecure text.

Answer (score 1):

try this (when you're done editing):

```
textField.frame.size.width = textField.intrinsicContentSize.width
```